# Nested if function in EXCEL for replacing the lowest value in the three cloumn with the fourth column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four columns
I want to replace the lowest grade in Test 1, Test 2, and Test 3 with Test 4 if the Value of Test 4 is bigger!

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnAw3.png)

But if Test 4 has the lowest grade, I will not do anything and keep the original grades:

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yw4H.png)

I wrote the following function in EXCEL but it does not work.

```
IF((AND(C2>F2, D2>F2, E2>F2)), A2+B2+C2+D2+E2+F2+G2, IF ((AND(C2<F2, C2<D2, C2>E2)), A2+B2+F2+D2+E2+F2+G2, IF ((AND(D2<F2, D2<C2, D2>E2)), A2+B2+C2+F2+E2+F2+G2, IF ((AND(E2<F2, E2<D2, E2>C2)), A2+B2+C2+D2+F2+F2+G2)))))
```

Comment: Have you ever used VBA before?  This seems like something better suited as a programming task.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I want to send an spreadsheet to my students, so that they know how I will calculate their final grade. I think it is easier for students to run.

Comment: Are you their maths teacher or computer science teacher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you cannot replace another cell's value with a formula but you can substitute another value in a SUM operation, even conditionally. This works on your two samples.

```
=SUM(A2:D2)+MAX(D2, MIN(A2:C2))-MIN(A2:C2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems great!  I'll try on some students' grades to make sure it works for all possibilities. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(COLUMN()=7,SUM($C5:$F5),IF(AND(C2=MIN($C2:$E2),C2<$F2),$F2,C2))
```

in C5 (?) and copied across.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll ty  this code too. I appreciate it.